# Hyperledger Fabric world state, is it immutable?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, immutability

In blockchain technology, we have learned that blocks are immutable. In `Hyperledger Fabric` we have world state that is implemented using `GoLevelDB` or `CouchDB`.

First, as far as I know, I can delete a key-pair in a `Chaincode`. So, is it really **immutable**?

Second, in `Bitcoin` and `Ethereum`, all data is included in blocks and hash of all the data in a block embedded in the next block makes it impossible to alter previous blocks easily. So, **how does the world state differ from a block in HLF**? Can world state database make HLF vulnerable to attacks?

Answer (score 1):

The world state is basically just a resulting state of all the previous transactions. By deleting a key-pay in Chaincode you just perform a transaction that tells that "now there is no value stored in the state by this key" but all the previous transactions will still be there, it's basically the same as if you put let's say an empty string in some Ethereum mapping by some key.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `immutable` refer to all the transactions happened. You can't change any **past transaction**. World state is basically the latest view of the data (key-value pairs). Nothing to do with the immutability, if world state is immutable, how could there be new value, right?
2. Of course they work in the same way (Therefore, no vulnerability for the world state to be mutable). Although HLF does not use proof-of-work to calculate a nonce, all block contains the hash of the previous block to form a "chain". You can refer to the documentation key concept "Ledger" section to further study what is in a block.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric World State is not immutable but is only meant to have the latest state so you can quickly propose or endorse transactions based on the current state.

If you intentionally tamper and remove any key's or change the values in world state

- If you keep transacting without involving the tampered record, it may continue to remain wrong in your world-state till any transaction involving the tampered record is performed.
- If you propose a transaction based on the tampered record, other nodes will not endorse your transaction.
- If any other node proposes a transaction that involved the tampered record, it will result in your malicious node not being able to endorse the transaction but If other nodes provide necessary endorsement and the transaction goes through, the world state would be updated automatically and undo the tampering.

Hope this clarifies.